# How do I use Flutters Navigator with a BLoC setup?

Tags: flutter, bloc, navigator

I am writing an app that is making use of Cubits for state management. It is an audiobook player and you can look up the different audiobooks and display them. Then jump to the author or the series and explore around your library.

As it stands at the moment the different pages you move between are being rendered using a BLoC builder as follows.

```
    class ScreenSelector extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return BlocBuilder<ScreenCubit, ScreenState>(builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is HomeScreenState) {
                    return HomeScreen();
                }

                if (state is BookScreenState) {
                    return BookScreen(bookId: state.bookId);
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
    }
```

There are genre, author and series screens as well that will work the same as the book screen. There is a cubit that is emitting the appropriate state hooked up to different clickable widgets on the home and book page. This all works as expected. There is also an authorization flow that is worked to either render the HomeScreen or go to the Loginscreen. This also works nicely.

But i'd like to use a navigator instead so you can go backwards to previous pages. That seems like the right way to navigate but i'm lost on getting Navigator to work with BLoC.

I tried constructing the MaterialPageRoutes and pushing them when the state changes instead of loading the page and I tried converting the BlocBuilder to a BlocListener. Trying to push the page in the BlocBuilder did nothing and the BlocListener would only ever throw an exception.

If anybody has a pointer to how I might go about doing this or knows of a simple example of using Cubits with Navigator 1.0 in flutter I would be most grateful. I looked around but all of the examples I found either mixed in an authorization example and I got lost.

I expect i'm approaching the problem incorrectly but i'm not sure where I have gone off track.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just have really crappy GoogleFu and you can find the solution to the problem at

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesflutternavigation

It has a nice recipe that explains it well by the author of Bloc